# Need help in printing a special kind star using loop

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to write some codes to make an octagon and print a 8-pointed star if I am not wrong in the octagon. I wrote the codes already but the problem is that the codes are too long and I have to write a shorter one using a loop. I wanted to know if I could use loops in the following codes to shorten it.
Here are the codes (I only have access to the part of my codes where it prints the star and I only wanna short that part):

```
From turtle import *
forward(50) 
left(40) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(90) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(80) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(90) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(90) 
forward(50) 
right(50) 
forward(50) 
left(90) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(80) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50) 
left(90) 
forward(50) 
right(40) 
forward(50)
```

Can you shorten the codes if possible?

Comment: Yes you can use loops to improve the code. What loops do you know about in python?

Comment: What patterns do you see? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @quamrana the loops i currently know is not much honestly since i am very new to python. I only know how to make an unlimited loop using while True and for i in range(). I think that i have to use a loop in another loop or something like that. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest finding a mathematical formula that will generate the point coordinates. From there you can use that list of points in a loop and move from one to the next.

Comment: `from turtle import *` is dangerous, bringing 150+ variables into the global namespace. I'd switch to instance mode as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the best solution, and I didn't actually run it with turtle to check the final shape, but it should give you some ideas.

There is a consistent pattern of:

```
left(left_angle)
forward(50)
right(right_angle)
forward(50)
```

With one additional `forward(50)` at either the start or end of the pattern, depending on how you look at it.

Thanks to that pattern, we can break this down into a list of pairs of turn angles, and then loop over that list. Here I have also set the distance moved forward into a variable so that it can be easily changed through the entire pattern.

```
FORWARD_DISTANCE = 50
turns = [(40, 40), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40), (90, 50), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40)]

forward(FORWARD_DISTANCE) # initial line

for l_angle, r_angle in turns:
    left(l_angle)
    forward(FORWARD_DISTANCE)
    right(r_angle)
    forward(FORWARD_DISTANCE)
```